# Why do I have to put this function static

Tags: c++, static

I am trying t understand the `Named Constructor Idiom` in the example I have

Point.h

```
class Point
{
    public:
        static Point rectangular(float x, float y);
    private:
        Point(float x, float y);
        float x_, y_;
};
inline Point::Point(float x, float y) : x_(x), y_(y) {}
inline Point Point::rectangular(float x, float y) {return Point(x,y);}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "include\Point.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Point p1 = Point::rectangular(2,3.1);
    return 0;
}
```

It does not compile If `Point::rectangular` is not `static` and I don't understand why...

Comment: Do you understand what the `static` keyword does in this context?

Comment: no I am afraid... For me static means that the function is not called on an object but belong to the whole class

Comment: Right. Now think if it _wasn't_ static, how would you use it to create a new object? You'd need to have an object already, so you could call the member function, but if you have an object already you don't need to construct another one.

Comment: Ok!, if it wasn't static I should call it on an object, this is the whole point, we are building one...
Thanks

Comment: In this context, the `static` keyword allows access to a function without requiring an object instance; on the other hand, class data members can't be used because there is no object pointer passed.

Comment: btw, `#include "include\Point.h"` is too Windows. Use backslash `/` for path separation, or include `include` in your list of includes, and don't include `include/` in your `#include`.

Comment: yep just testing things on Code::Blocks for simplicity... Thx everybody

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this context, the `static` keyword in front of a function means that this function does not belong to any particular *instance* of the class. Normal class methods have an implicit `this` parameter that allow you to access the members of that specific object. However `static` member functions do not have the implicit `this` parameter.  Essentially, a static functions is the same as a free function, except it has access to the protected and private members of the class it is declared in.

This means you can call static functions without an instance of that class. Instead of needing something like

```
Point p1;
p1.foo();
```

You simply do this:

```
Point::foo();
```

If you tried to call a non static function like this, the compiler will complain, because non-static functions need some value to assign to the implicit `this` parameter, and `Point::foo()` doesn't supply such a value.

Now the reason you want `rectangular(int, int)` to be static is because it is used for constructing a new `Point` object from scratch. You do not not need an existing `Point` object to construct the new point so it makes sense to declare the function `static`.